# ggplot2 histogram of factors showing the probability mass instead of count

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use the excellent ggplot2 using the bar geom to plot the probability mass rather than the count. However, using `aes(y=..density..)` the distribution does not sum to one (but is close). I think the problem might be due to the default binwidth for factors. Here is an example of the problem,

```
age <- c(rep(0,4), rep(1,4))
mppf <- c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0)
data.test <- as.data.frame(cbind(age,mppf))
data.test$age <- as.factor(data.test$age)
data.test$mppf <- as.factor(data.test$mppf)
p.test.density <- ggplot(data.test, aes(mppf, group=age, fill=age)) +
geom_bar(aes(y=..density..), position='dodge') +
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1))
dev.new()
print(p.test.density)
```

I can get around this problem by keeping the x-variable as continuous and setting `binwidth=1`, but it doesn't seem very elegant.

```
data.test$mppf.numeric <- as.numeric(data.test$mppf)
p.test.density.numeric <- ggplot(data.test, aes(mppf.numeric, group=age, fill=age)) + 
geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), position='dodge', binwidth=1)+ 
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1))
dev.new()
print(p.test.density.numeric)
```

Comment: If x is not continuous, you are not plotting a histogram by definition.

Comment: @Roland and @Richie, thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately,I get the same problem using `geom_bar` - which I had also tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you almost have it figured out, and would have once you realized you needed a bar plot and not a histogram.

The default width for bars with categorical data is .9 (See `?stat_bin`. The help page for `geom_bar` doesn't give the default bar width but does send you to `stat_bin` for further reading.).  Given that, your plots show the correct density for a bar width of .9.  Simply change to a width of 1 and you will see the density values you expected to see.

```
ggplot(data.test, aes(x = mppf, group = age, fill = age)) +
  geom_bar(aes(y=..density..), position = "dodge", width = 1) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,1))
```

Comment: awesome. Thanks for the `width=1`. I had spent ages trying to figure this out. I had presumed the stat_bin would default to width=1. Next time I will drill down through the help files a bit further.

Comment: By the way `geom_histogram` defaults to `geom_bar` with factors so adding 'width=1' also works with geom_histogram.